# Mark AWS lambda parent segment as fault or error

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, segment, aws-xray

Is it possible to mark the parent segment of an aws-lambda function as fault or error?

Aws documentation states that *[you can't add annotations and metadata to the parent segment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-lambda.html)* but I can't seem to find if it is possible to mark the parent segment as fault or error.

Marking the subsegments with fault/error works as expected with:

```
AWSXRayRecorder recorder = AWSXRayRecorder.Instance;
recorder.BeginSubsegment("X");
recorder.MarkFault();
recorder.EndSubsegment();
```

results in:

[image: subsegment X result]

But it won't mark the parent segment as having a fault, only the subsegment.

[image: lambda_one segments]

How do I manage to mark the parent segment as "fault"?

Answer (score 0):

The parent segment is managed by lambda service. It is not possible to modify the contents of that segment.
That segment is marked as error or fault only when your function throws an unhandled exception.

Currently your only option is to add annotations to X in your example. Say you can add annotation `xfailed` with value `true`.

What is your exact usecase for marking a fault on that segment? Is it searching for traces based on some criteria?

In that case you can also use a filter expression like `annotation.xfailed = true`. This will find traces which match this criteria.

You may also create a group with this criteria. That way you can look at a service map which comprises of only traces that matched this criteria. You can read more about groups here:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-xray-adds-the-ability-to-group-traces/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html#xray-concepts-groups

Note: Groups are billed by the number of retrieved traces that match the filter expression.

Please let me know your usecase in more detail.

Comment: For the use case, I want to visually show in the service graph when an error occurred in a lambda function. I would expect to be able to mark the parent segment as a fault if an error occurred somewhere in the function. Now I can only mark a subsegment as a fault, which is visible in the trace itself but not visually in the service graph.

Comment: Yes that is not currently possible since the segment is managed by lambda. Also the lambda segment is Green because the function execution itself did not throw an exception. At least that's the behavior today.

Comment: To see it visually in the service graph, you can add an annotation to the subsegment for such cases. Then you can create a group with that filter expression as I described in the answer above. That way you can see two service graphs - the default one as you see today and the one for the group based on the filter expression. The group will only contain traces that match the filter. For the group, you are billed only for the number of traces that match the filter as I mentioned in the answer. If the failures that you want to track visually are infrequent then the cost will be relatively low.

Comment: So for my question "Is it possible to mark the parent segment of an aws-lambda function as fault or error?" the simple answer is no.

Comment: Correct, No at present.